# Can Weblogic deployment be configured to explode subordinate JARs as well?

Tags: jar, weblogic, exploded

Can Weblogic deployment be configured to explode subordinate JARs as well?

We have a JSF project that is comprised of more than a dozen different projects. Ultimately it is compiled into 3 EARs (system1, system2, and EAI for intersystem communication) which are deployed to weblogic exploded.

When I need to edit XHTML files, I don't want to go through the 15 minute build process. I want to see my change 5 seconds later. So I go to the deployment folder and edit my XHTML file there. If I'm happy with my changes, I copy it back to the project.

This has greatly tightened up my development loop, saving hours of time!

**Enter the problem:**

Common XHTML between both systems as part of a common-io project/jar.  So even though my weblogic EAR for system1 is exploded -- all of those common XHTMLs are locked up inside that common-io.jar.

Sure, I could manually uncompress it and delete the original jar. Which has a filehandle lock. Which means restarting weblogic. Which means waiting at least 5 minutes. I'm used to 5 seconds.

**What I am looking for:**

I guess I would call this "super exploded". I don't just want the EAR I deploy to be exploded; I want the subordinate JARs to be exploded too.

**What would be perfect:**

I deploy via Weblogic.Deployer at the commandline. I'd just LOVE it if there was an option I didn't know about that would explode all subordinate JARs.

Comment: You can deploy a "directory" that has already been exploded rather than an ear file if you want. However, I'm not sure the kind of changes you want to make will be replicated without a server restart

Comment: True, but we have a deployment framework that is pretty specific. It has to be the EAR file. It deploys exploded... But not *as* exploded as I'd like ;)